# Cual es la manera mas sencilla de quitarle comas a una cadena en java

Tags: java

He realizado un programa que tenía como finalidad crear un arreglo o vector unidimensional de N números ingresados por el usuario, de manera visual; para ello utilice un un `Textbox`, el cual es llenado con números sucesivos, separados por comas; ya que la idea de preguntar un límite cerrado y luego ir introduciendo los números uno por uno, me parecía un tanto engorroso.

Luego de ya obtener la cadena de números separados por comas, remplacé las comas por espacios vacíos y le hice un split, para convertir esa cadena en una arreglo de cadenas conteniendo los números ingresados, para luego calcular el promedio de los valores introducidos, as{i como el promedio de las posiciones pares del mismo, lo cual funciona.

Solo quería saber si existe una manera mas sencilla de hacerlo, o alguna otra alternativa utilizando el mismo `split`.

Answer (score 1):

## Dividir una cadena separada por comas en un arreglo de cadenas

`Split` soporta dividir una cadena separada por comas. Solamente debes pasar la coma como caracter separador en la llamada a la función:

```
public static void main(String... args) { 
    String cadena = "Google,Apple,Microsoft"; 
    String[] valores = cadena.split(","); 
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(valores)); 
}
```

Esto va a imprimir:

```
[Google, Apple, Microsoft]
```

## Quitar las comas de una cadena

Si solo quieres *quitar* las comas, puedes utilizar `replace` para sustituir todas las apariciones de la coma, por ejemplo, por un caracter de espacio:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {  
  String cadena = "Google,Apple,Microsoft";  
  String cadenaSinComas = cadena.replace(",", " ");  
  System.out.println(cadenaSinComas);  
}
```

Esto va a imprimir:

```
Google Apple Microsoft
```

Comment: El segundo caso es lo que yo habia echo exactamente, pero queria saber si existe alguna otra alternativa aparte de aquella

Comment: Respondí con ambas, porque en el título parece que la duda es como quitar las comas, pero el texto apunta a separar luego el texto en varias cadenas. En ese caso, la primera opción es la más directa.

Comment: No tengo problema en separar, solo quierto quitarle directamente las comas, es decir tengo varios numeros separados por comas, ejemplo: 5,2,3, a los cuales aislo, teniendo 1 2 3, los cuales posteriormente meto en un vector de tipo entero

Comment: Por ello, tenia curiosidad de saber si existia alguna otra alternativa a replace

Comment: En ese caso no es necesario quitar las comas, utiliza `split(",")`, tal como indico en la primera parte de mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar

```
cadena=cadena.replaceAll(",","")
```

Comment: Entiendo que esto no es lo que pide el op porque quiere generar un vector nuevo con los elementos separados por la , el replaceAll recibe una cadena y devuelve otra, un saludo!

Comment: Tienes razón, leí mal la pregunta. Se podría seguir utilizando esto. Después del replace() podríamos usar un cadena.split(" ") y separar con espacios la palabra en vez de con nada.